# How to place content behind navigation bar ? Android

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-statusbar

I am developing an app that contains many text. I got viewpager with fragments that contain textviewes. I want this textview to fit all system window (behind status and navigation bar also). I am using fullscreen activity for this

Fragment XML

```
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/page_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:allowUndo="true"
    android:background="#ffffff" />
```

Activity XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="#ffffff"
tools:context="tsk.dan.librarian.activity.reader">


<FrameLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout2" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tester1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top" />


</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/reader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            android:maxHeight="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text=" "
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/reader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dsa"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/open"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Styles XML

```
   <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

Help me please!

Comment: It might be wise to post a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was very simple !If you want your content fullscreen(under status and navigation bar), you need to use FrameLayout without this line

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

So if you want such full screen content just delete this line or don't add it.